# How can I use react-hooks in a reactjs library dev environment?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I want to develop a reactjs library using react-hooks.

So I made a dev environment with webpack and webpack-dev-server.

Withiout using hooks it works well but when I use them I got the following error.

[image: Invalid hook call]

This is a repo to reproduce the bug : [Repo github](https://github.com/jeromelegrand/dooliz-lib)

This is a related conversation on github about the same issue : [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-580826656)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try moving the react and react-dom to dependencies(rather than dev-dependencies) inside package.json?

EDIT:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState('World');

   return (
        <div>
          <h1>{`Hello ${value}`}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => setValue('Hooks')}>Click</button>
        </div>
     )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Moving them into dependencies instead of dev-dependencies produce the same error.

Comment: Yes, I removed node_modules and yarn.lock and I ran ```yarn install && yarn prod ```

Comment: Idk, what i'm looking at as the linked repo is incomplete(?) or that was it? You mean by "env-test" folder that is the "without hooks it works well"? then start from there. and try applying the code I've pasted above.

Comment: If I use hooks inside env-test without calling my library (dooliz-lib) it works. But I want use dooliz-lib.

Comment: What is dooliz-lib to be exact? and why are you passing it directly to ReactDOM?

Comment: dooliz-lib will be a library that I will share. So we will can import it thruth package.json